# PGconn.connect .... where is disconnect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, connect

**Environment:**

psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.3
Rails 5.1.1
Ruby 2.4.1p111

**Question:**

I may have a large group of (Devise) users each of whom is a separate Postgres user, e.g. SomePostgresRole01, SomePostgresRole02, etc.

I can successfully do:

```
conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432,"","","db_development","SomePostgresRole01","SomePassword")
```

I cannot find a conn.disconnect method.  Does such functionality exist?

Comment: `conn.close` should work

Comment: IIRC, you can pass a block, i.e. `PG.connect(...) { |conn| ... }` and the connection will be closed automatically afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

`.close()` can be used to close connection. Used `ensure` to make sure even after exception it will close database connection.

```
begin
   conn = PGconn.connect("localhost", 5432,"","","db_development","SomePostgresRole01","SomePassword")
rescue PG::Error => e
    puts e.message     
ensure
    conn.close if conn
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`#finish`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Connection#finish-instance_method) or `#close`, they're just alias' for the same thing.

Comment: Where is this documented?

Comment: You can see the link in my answer